# Unable to export the cross tabulated R results to Excel

Tags: r

I am doing a cross tabulation with top one variable and side many variables. when I run the below syntax
i.e.

```
data = read_sav("data_15W3.sav") 

Crossdata <- lapply(data, function(x) xtabs(~x+data$TREND)) 

write.csv(Crossdata, file = "D:/Crossdata.csv") 

write.xlsx(Crossdata, "Crossdata.xlsx")
```

in the 'R' GUI the results are produced. However, when I try to export them to Excel or CSV file I am getting an error message

> error in data.frame arguments imply differing number of rows

Since the variables have different rows. So is there any way where I could export the results to one Excel file?

Comment: Naturally, your result is a list. At least `write.csv` can handle only matrices/data.frames. Where does `write.xlsx` come from?